# Creating Ext2 partition using free windows tool

Tags: partitioning, filesystems, ext2

I want to intsall Linux on my hard drive on a seperate patition. Unfortunately, I can't find a free tool that will format a partition to ext2/3/4, and I can't access the windows made partition from an ubuntu live disk. Does anyone know of a tool/process they've used to do this before? I've tried:

EASEUS
MiniTool Partition Manager
Ext2 Volume Manager

But they all seem to lack this feature in their free iterations. Ext2 Volume Manager gives me the option format my C drive to ext2, but not a new volume. Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you delete the partition you created in Windows and create the partition you want in free space during the Linux installation process?

Answer (score 0):

I frequently use a [gparted live cd](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/download.php) to shrink a windows partition (NTFS OR FAT32) and make the  change i need on a hard drive. with some linux distro you can shrink the windows partition with gparted and then use the ' use free space ' option while installing linux.